# Building a polymorphic assocation from the belongs_to side

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Consider an application that consists of various user types, each of which have different profiles. During registration, the user is allowed to pick his/her user type (ie, buyer or seller).

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profileable, :polymorphic => true
  PROFILE_TYPES = %w[Buyer Seller]
end

class Buyer < ActiveRecord::Base
  # this is like a buyer profile
  has_one :user, :as => :profileable
end

class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base
  # this is like a seller profile
  has_one :artist, :as => :profileable
end
```

The `PROFILE_TYPES` array is used in a `options_for_select` in the new action of the Users controller, allowing the user to chose his/her user type.

**views/users/new.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= label_tag "Type" %>
  <%= f.select :profileable_type, options_for_select(User::PROFILE_TYPES) %>
  <%# ... %>
<% end %>
```

This saves the `profileable_type` attribute on the user correctly.

**My question is:** once the user is created, I would like them to be redirected to the Users#show action, where the correct profileable association is built. A form would be dynamically rendered depending on the profileable_type.

So far, I am able to render the correct form with the following

**views/users/show.html.erb**

```
<%= render "#{@user.profileable_type.downcase}/form" %>
```

However, this seems very unorthodox and I'm not quite sure how to build the association. Can I create the association when the user is initially created? Or should I create the association in Buyers#create and Sellers#create (where the above form points)? Should I model the data differently?

#### UPDATE

I have a this functioning properly by adding an `attr_accessor :user_type` to the User model.

**app/models/user.rb (updated)**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # ...
  attr_accessor :user_type

  def user_type=(type)
    self.profileable = type.constantize.new
    self.profileable.save
  end
end
```

**views/users/new.html.erb (updated)**

```
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :user_type %>
  <%= f.select :user_type, options_for_select(User::PROFILE_TYPES) %>
  <%# ... %>
<% end %>
```

This creates the correct associated object and saves the profileable_type and profileable_id on the user. However, this still seems awkward and hackish. Is the only way around this to have separate forms for each user type? That's not very DRY since I'm not forcing the user to fill out the specific attributes for the profile he/she selects until after the user itself is created.

Comment: You may want to look into using Single Table Inheritance. Seems appropriate in your case. This of course doesn't solve your problem, but it may make things easier for you.

Comment: I thought about this and didn't really like it. Are you suggesting `class Seller < User`? If so, the users table will be full of null attributes (the other user type attributes). Or do you suggest having `class Seller < User` and adding a `has_one :seller_profile`? I thought about that, and it seems to complicate the code a little more. Additional thoughts?

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about null attributes (after all, they don't use up any space), and the comments under your model definitions definitely point to a code smell ("it may be called Buyer, but actually it's a Profile.."). But it's still hard to tell which solution would work best for you.

Comment: I ruled out single table inheritance because I was under the impression that it was only best when your child classes have similar properties. I do not have that. In fact, the child classes wouldn't have one single property in common. To me, having a ton of null attributes points to a code (or design) smell. As for the comments under my models, I could have named the classes BuyerProfile and SellerProfile, but I thought it would be redundant.

Comment: You're probably right there. I would suggest posting a gist or similar, so that it's more clear what your intentions are with your models, since most of my advice so far is only based on assumptions.

Answer (score 0):

```
@user = @buyer.user.new(params[:user])
@user.save
```

This will save profileable_type and id automatically.  Also

```
<%= render "#{@user.profileable_type.downcase}/form" %>
```

is not good practice.  Your model knows too much about the view.  It looks like you should have a buyer and seller form, not a user form.  I'd need more info to give an example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I'm not sure it addresses my problem. Where does `@buyer` come from? `profileable_type` is determined by the `options_for_select` in the user signup form. Also, what do you mean that the model knows too much about the view?

Comment: @user.profileable_type is information about your model.  yet this is how you decide what view directory to look at.